# How can I get a blinking cursor after calling .focus() on a text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

This doesn't seem to happen automatically when using a `text area`, but does when using `text fields`.

For example, after a successful ajax request, I do stuff, and on the last line of my code, I apply `focus` to the `text area`.

```
$('textarea').focus();
```

This causes the cursor to show, but it doesn't blink as expected until I click in the textarea myself.

Is this default behaviour and is there a way to get the behaviour I want, i.e. make the cursor blink?

Kind regards

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean that when you do a `.focus()` on a `<textarea>` (as opposed to a `<input type="text">`), there is no blinking cursor? Can you still type in it?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question. I should have been more clear.

Comment: I think @LondonGuy means the ["text cursor" otherwise known as a "caret"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_cursor#Text_cursor), and not the mouse pointer (also called a cursor).

Comment: Is your browser up-to-date? Assuming you're talking about the "text cursor" [there doesn't seem to be any issue with getting the caret to blink when fields are focused dynamically](http://jsfiddle.net/bDAUV/).

Comment: Yea I mean text cursor/caret. It's not a browser issue as it's working  every where else, just not on text areas in my application. I'll dig deeper if it's not default behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the styling is set to show no cursor. 
Take a look here for examples and try to add it to your CSS for the input tag

[Cursor examples in CSS](http://www.echoecho.com/csscursors.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The StackOverflow text area I'm typing this into has (a) `cursor: auto` set and (b) a blinking cursor on focus.